# Regex to validate textbox length

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this RegEx that validates input (in javascript) to make sure user didn't enter more than 1000 characters in a textbox:

```
^.{0,1000}$
```

It works ok if you enter text in one line, but once you hit Enter and add new line, it stops matching. How should I change this RegEx to fix that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wish is this:

```
/^[\s\S]{0,1000}$/
```

The reason is that `.` won't match newlines.

A better way however is to not use regular expressions and just use `<text area element>.value.length`

Comment: This regex I believe will not accept "garbage" caracters, which I want to be able to accept.

Comment: It will accept everything `\s` is all whitespace and `\S` is all non-whitespace, together they are everything™. But again, don't use regex for this, it is just plain wrong.

Comment: your suggestion worked, thanks! But I still don't understand why it's wrong. I realize that if I was just doing comparison in javascript, I should've gone the string.length way; but I do want to use a built-in asp.net regex validator instead of writing code, and it doesn't perform that bad.

Comment: @Andrey: There is a saying: "If all you have is a hammer, every problem will start to look like a nail" Just because a certain tool will do a job adequately, doesn't make it the right tool for the job - make sure to have many tools in your toolbox, and pick the right one for the job at hand, that way you'll end up a better programmer ;)

Comment: I agree, but I also follow the principle of the least code for the task - if I can do validation with built-in tool (RegularExpressionValidator class in asp.net) or write my own, I will use built-in one and concentrate my efforts elsewhere. I only have 20 hours a day for coding :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `.` doesn't match the newline character. I suppose you could use something like this:

```
^[.\r\n]{0,1000}$
```

It should work (as long as you're [not using `m`](http://javascript.about.com/library/blre18.htm)), but do you really need a regular expression here? Why not just use the [`.length` property](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-length.php)?

Obligatory [jwz quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

---

**Edit:** You could use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) to check the length instead of using Regex. MSDN has an example available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET regex validator

Comment: @Andrey use an appropriate validator.

Comment: that regex didn't work. The one Martin suggested did though, so I'm all set.

Comment: Thanks for the link regarding custom validator, but it would not be trivial to implement in my case. I have 20 boxes on the form and each has different max length requirement.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to verify the length of the input wouldn't it be easier to just verify the length of the string?

```
if (input.length > 1000)
    // fail validation
```